# What is this red point in html code?

Tags: php, html, smarty

Well, this is really weird question...

Somehow i found this red point:
[image]
to be problem as a new \r\n\ in output in template...

Well, i really wanna know what is this point?

This appears between two include tags in smarty, files are in UTF-8.

Somehow escaping this works great in php:

```
$output = preg_replace("//", "", $output );//magic! escaping redpoint
```

Really would appreciate your answers, cause this is a problem for 2 sites already...

Comment: Could be a unicode character.

Comment: `files are in UTF-8` you need to remove the BOM from your php files.

Comment: Thank you. Removing BOM with text editor helped.